# Repairing Minipimer knife blade

Tags: equipment, hand-blender

The knife blade of my beloved ancient Minipimer has become loose. What can I do to fix it tighter to the axle. Both the blade and the axle are all metal.

Comment: Hello @sarab, welcome to the site. Some pictures may help here.

Comment: Could you attach a retaining ring/e-clip to it?

Comment: Same thing happened to my mother. She just bought a new blade assembly. Works like a charm.